# Powershell replace filenames

Tags: powershell

I am using the same logic i use for renaming but having difficulty getting this to work, are the failures to work due to the naming convention?

Example file:
filename.xxxx.xx_xxx (2).jpg

Expected results:
filename.xxxx.xx_xxx.jpg

Here's what I have:

```
$toRename = Get-ChildItem ".\files" 

    foreach($x in $toRename){
    $x | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace " (2)", "" }
    }
```

I added a `-WhatIf` and the filename simply doesn't change. I must be missing something obvious but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis, they are a special character.

```
foreach($x in $toRename)
{
    Rename-Item -Path $x.FullName -NewName ($x.Name -replace "\s\(2\)")
}
```

Comment: This is correct; `-replace` uses regular expressions for the first parameter. See [`Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might have something to do with the parenthesis... also ty @JeffZeitlin for the material.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use $_ in your foreach but $x.

1. Use "foreach"

```
$toRename = Get-ChildItem ".\files"
foreach($x in $toRename){
    $x | Rename-Item -NewName { $x.Name.Replace(" (2)", "") }
}
```

2. Use ForEach-Object

```
Get-ChildItem ".\files"  | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName $_.Name.Replace(" (2)", "") }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am going with the second answer tho as it explains why my initial script didn't work (the special character).